# Converting a Text .txt document to CSV .csv Using a Delimiter

Tags: python, csv, delimiter, txt

I'd like to create a CSV from a TXT file. I have a text file with lines (300 lines+) separated by backslashes. I'd like each line to be a separate row, and each backslash to be a separate new column.

The text file looks like:

```
example 1\example 2\example 3\example 4
test 1\test 2\test 3\test 4
```

I'd like the CSV to look like:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Example 1 | Example 2 | Example 3 | Example 4 |
| Test 1 | Test 2 | Test 3 | Test 4 |

So far I have:

```
import csv
with open('Report.txt') as report:
    report_txt = report.read()
    with open('Report.csv','w',newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(report_txt)
```

I know I need to use \ as a delimiter, but I'm not sure how. Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's just another CSV dialect, using `delim="\\"`

Comment: Trivially `tr '\' ',' <file.txt >file.csv` if you don't need to worry about quoting (that is, none of the data contains a literal backslash or a literal comma).

Comment: You could probably pull it off with `for line in report_txt.splitlines: writer.writerow(line.split("\\"))` though reading a single line at a time would be simpler and more elegant, and this still doesn't handle quoting or literal backslashes in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your delimiter like this (escape the `\`):

```
reader = csv.reader(open("Report.csv"), delimiter="\\")
```

Code:

```
import csv
with open('Report.txt') as report:
    reader = csv.reader(report, delimiter="\\")
    with open('Report_output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        for line in reader:
            writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Thanks Jarvis, would you mind posting entire line of code? I can't make it work ...

Comment: Thanks so much! I copy/pasted this, the text name is correct but I keep getting 'ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.' Any idea what's happening? Really appreciate the help.

Comment: Check the latest edit, I made a mistake before, should be working now.

Answer (score 0):

First you got to split the string based on the delimeter. You can achieve this by using the `split` operator or regex.

```
import csv
    
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as in_file:
        stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
        lines = (line.split("\\") for line in stripped if line)
```

Then pretty much write it to the csv.

```
with open('report.csv', 'w') as out_file:
            writer = csv.writer(out_file)
            writer.writerows(lines)
```

Tweak your code accordingly. The concept is pretty much the same. Note the double backslash is to account for the escape character.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to convert that text into CSV, you can just replace every "\" character with ";" and you'll have a valid CSV file.

Else, if you want to do something with the parsed data before reexporting to CSV, you can read the file line by line and use the split() Method with "\", then rejoin and write line by line, like here:

```
with open('in.txt') as input_file:
    with open('out.csv','a') as output_file:
        txt_line = input_file.readline()
        while txt_line:
            cells = txt_line.split("\\")
            
            # Do something with each cell...
            
            csv_line = ";".join(cells)
            
            output_file.write(csv_line)
            txt_line = input_file.readline()
```